# construct a class with a dataframe as argument in python

Tags: python, oop, object, constructor

I am new to working with Python and have only worked with object orientation to a small extend in Java.
Now I want to construct a class which has a data frame as attribute which should be part of the constructor. However I have no idea how to achieve this. I tried the following for the class (the method is just for testing whether the code works)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
class ProcessData():
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.data = frame
    
    def time(self):
        return (self.data['time'])
```

and the following for using it

```
test = ProcessData(data)
print(test.time())
```

with data being my data frame which I want to pass with the column 'time'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: oh sorry, thanks, of course I ment that. However I did not do this in my code and it should not be the error

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate define the 'time' column in your data variable. For example.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time'])
data['time'] = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: but then I would not use the dataframe 'frame' with which I want to initialize the object, right? I am also not even sure whether I even need to declare data outside the class.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your initial question. I edited my answer. You can use your code as is simply by initiating the variable data correctly. Note that the data variable does not need to be defined before the class.